# Struts 1 Delete Confirmation using display tag in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts, displaytag

Im trying to show a delete confirmation box once the user clicks the delete button within the display:column. I have the dialog to show up but once the user confirms that he wants to delete the action is not getting called. The page just reloads without the row being deleted. Without the delete confirmation the row will be deleted successfully. Im doing something wrong with the confirmation. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

What I have right now is:

jQuery:

```
$(".btnShowDeleteConfirmation").click(function (e)
          {
             ShowDialog(true);
             e.preventDefault();
          });

          $("#btnClose, #btnNo").click(function (e)
          {
             HideDialog();
             e.preventDefault();
          });

          $("#btnYes").click(function (e)
          {

            });
```

Javascript:

```
   function deleteEntry(rowId)
  {
    document.getElementById('rowId').value=rowId;
    document.forms['myForm'].action='/myAction/deleteAction.action?method=deleteRow';
    document.forms['myForm'].submit;       
  }
```

display tag table:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="mainForm" name="MyFormBean">

<display:table requestURIcontext="true"  requestURI="/unavailability/loadUnavailability.action?method=loadForm" uid="myList" name="requestScope.unavailList" class="simple" pagesize="10" defaultsort="2" sort="list"  cellspacing="0" excludedParams="*">    

<display:column  property="startDate" title="Start Date" width="18%"   decorator="com.mhngs.util.DisplayTagDateWrapper" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable"/>
<display:column  property="endDate" title="End Date" width="18%"  decorator="com.mhngs.util.DisplayTagDateWrapper" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
<display:column  property="reason" title="Comments" width="30%" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />   

<display:column media="html" width="10%" class="btnShowDeleteConfirmation">
<a href="#">Delete</a>
</display:column>


</display:table> 
<input type="hidden" name="rowId" id="rowId" />
</form>
```

HTML: This will be displayed once user clicks the delete button

```
<div id="overlay" class="delete_overlay"></div>

        <div id="dialog_delete" class="delete_overlay">
        <form method="post" action="">  
            <table style="width: 100%; border: 0px;" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                 <tr>
                    <td class="web_dialog_title">Delete Row Confirmation</td>
                    <td class="web_dialog_title align_right"><a href="#" id="btnClose">Close</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 15px;">
                        <label>You seleted a row to be deleted</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                <input id="btnYes" type="submit" value="Yes" onClick="javascript:deleteEntry('<c:out  value="${myList.rowId}"/>')"/>
                <input id="btnNo" type="button" value="No" />
             </td>
             </tr>
             </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified form name in html. Where have you mentioned "myForm" name in the form tag?

```
<form name="myForm" .. >
```